# Proving $\sum \frac{b+c}{9(a^2+3bc)+4(a+b+c)^2}\geqslant \frac{1}{4(a+b+c)}$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, uvw

For $a,b,c>0.$ Prove$:$ $$\sum \dfrac{b+c}{9(a^2+3bc)+4(a+b+c)^2}\geqslant \dfrac{1}{4(a+b+c)}$$

SOS solution$:$ $$\dfrac{1}{8(a+b+c)}\sum{\dfrac { \left( 52\,{a}^{2}+95\,ab-142\,ac+52\,{b}^{2}-142\,bc+103\,{c
}^{2} \right) \left( a-b \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 13\,{a}^{2}+35\,bc+8\,
ab+8\,ac+4\,{b}^{2}+4\,{c}^{2} \right) \left( 13\,{b}^{2}+35\,ac+4\,{
a}^{2}+8\,ab+8\,bc+4\,{c}^{2} \right) }}\geqslant 0,$$
which is clearly true.

I also found a proof by pqr method$:$

Need to prove$:$ $$208\,{p}^{6}-432\,{p}^{4}q-5805\,{p}^{3}r-972\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+32724\,p
qr-2187\,{q}^{3}-46656\,{r}^{2} \geqslant 1728(-4{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18pqr-4{q}^{3}-27{r}^{2})\geqslant 0$$

Note that $$1728(-4{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18pqr-4{q}^{3}-27{r}^{2})=1728(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \geqslant 0.$$
We are only need to prove the left.
It's $$27\,p \left( 41\,{p}^{2}+60\,q \right) r+208\,{p}^{6}-432\,{p}^{4}q-
2700\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+4725\,{q}^{3} \geqslant 0.$$
By Schur degree $6$ we have$:$ $$r\geqslant -\frac49\,{p}^{3}+{\frac {11}{9}}\,pq+\frac{1}{9}\sqrt {7\,{p}^{6}-25\,{p}^{4}q+
4\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+36\,{q}^{3}}.$$
Let $p=1$ then $q \leqslant \frac{p^2}{3} =\frac{1}{3}$. Hence it's enough to prove$:$
$$-284+201\,q+123\,\sqrt {7-25\,q+4\,{q}^{2}+36\,{q}^{3}}-720\,{q}^{2}+
180\,q\sqrt {7-25\,q+4\,{q}^{2}+36\,{q}^{3}}+4725\,{q}^{3} \geqslant 0.$$
Since $$284-201\,q+720\,{q}^{2}-4725\,{q}^{3} \geqslant 0 \quad \forall \quad 0< q\leqslant \frac{1}{3}$$
So we are only need to prove $$\left( 1-3\,q \right)  \left( 7441875\,{q}^{5}-176175\,{q}^{4}+
172665\,{q}^{3}-904113\,{q}^{2}+121644\,q+25247 \right)  \geqslant 0,$$
which is true because $0< q\leqslant \frac{1}{3}.$

Done.

Is there any other proof (without Buffalo Way of course)$?$

Comment: @RiverLi is my SOS and pqr solution ok?

Comment: The SOS needs the help of computer?

Comment: @RiverLi yes by my SOS tool. But we can get this SOS by the same way as Mr. Mike by hand.

Comment: Sure. But your SOS is obtained by your SOS tool rather than by hand. It is ok as a computer solution.

Comment: Why do you only need to check for $p=1$?

Comment: @Diger Because the original inequality is homogeneous. So we may assume $a+b+c=1$ which mean $p=a+b+c=1.$

Comment: Sorry, stupid question. That is equivalent to substituting $x=q/p^2$ and $y=r/p^3$. But why is your inequality $$r\geqslant -49\,{p}^{3}+{\frac {11}{9}}\,pq+\frac{1}{9}\sqrt {7\,{p}^{6}-25\,{p}^{4}q+4\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+36\,{q}^{3}}$$ valid? Or even useful? It is somewhat negative so even the bound $r\geq 0$ would be better than this bound unless there is an error. In fact I can make $r$ arbitrarily small, for example by letting $c\rightarrow 0$ such that $p=a+b$ and $q=ab$, but $r=0$.

Comment: Besides $$27\,p \left( 41\,{p}^{2}+60\,q \right) r+208\,{p}^{6}-432\,{p}^{4}q-
2700\,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+4725\,{q}^{3} \geqslant 0$$ is not even true for $q=p^2/3$ and $r=0$.

Comment: @Diger When $p^2=3q,r=0$ we have $a^2+b^2+c^2=ab+bc+ca, abc=0$ which means $a=b=c=0.$ So it's WRONG!!!

Comment: @tthnew Please check your Schur degree 6.

Comment: @RiverLi It was typo, I edit it.

Comment: Yes, now it is correct.

Comment: Now it works. No need to go all Buffalo still! How did you obtain your Schurr degree 6? Starting with which symmetric polynomial in a,b,c?

Comment: So apparently the Schurr degree 6 inequality is equivalent to $$\sum_{cyc} a^4(a-c)(a-b) \geq 0\,.$$ Can this be converted to a SOS?

Comment: @Diger I use my program in Maple to get Schur degree 6 into pqr's form.

Comment: SOS form$:$ $$\sum a^4(a-b)(a-c)=\frac{1}{2} \sum  \left( a{b}^{3}+{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-c{a}^{3}-c{b}^{3}-cb{a}^{2}-c{b}^{2}a+
{a}^{3}b+{a}^{4}+{b}^{4} \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^{2}$$

Comment: @Diger  Actually we need a lower bound of $r$. Besides the Schur degree 6, the following also works: 
Since $-4p^3r+p^2q^2+18pqr-4q^3-27r^2 = (a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \ge 0$
we have
$r \ge -\frac{2}{27}p^3 + \frac{1}{3}pq - \frac{2}{27}\sqrt{(p^2 - 3q)^3}$.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, because $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \geqslant 0$ is stronger than Sschur degree 6. We can let $p=1,q=\frac{1-t^2}{3}.$ It would be look better.

Comment: @tthnew Yes, with it we eliminate the sqrt sign.

Comment: @RiverLi For $a+b+c=1,ab+bc+ca=\frac{1-t^2}{3} \quad (\, t \in [0,1] \,) $ I found that the following inequality is true$:$ ${\dfrac {{a}^{2}}{b}}+{\dfrac {{b}^{2}}{c}}+{\dfrac {{c}^{2}}{a}}\geqslant {\dfrac {3\,{t}^{4}-4\,{t}^{3}-5\,{t}^{2}-2\,t-1}{ \left( t-1 \right) \left( 1+2\,t \right)  \left( t+1 \right) }}$

Comment: @tthnew Very nice. The same as my result but you eliminate the sqrt sign. Using $ab+bc+ca = \frac{1-t^2}{3}$ is better than $ab + bc + ca = \frac{1}{3+t^2}$. My result: Let $a, b, c > 0; \ a+b+c = 1; \ ab+bc+ca = \frac{1}{3+t^2}\ $ ($t\ge 0$). I think that
$$\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{a} \ge
t^2-\frac{1}{t^2+3} + \frac{2(t^6+4t^4+4t^2+4)}{t^3(t^2+3)\sqrt{t^2+3}+2(t^2+3)}.$$

Comment: Yes, when use $ab+bc+ca=\frac{1-t^2}{3},$ my program work!

Comment: @tthnew Similarly, your program works for: Let $a, b, c > 0; \ a+b+c = 1; \ ab+bc+ca = \frac{1}{3+t^2}\ $ ($t\ge 0$). Then
$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a} \ge (t+1)^2+\frac{2}{t+1}.$$

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, of course!

Comment: @RiverLi Could I know your email address?

Comment: @tthnew We can discuss math on AoPS private message.

Comment: @RiverLi are you are dragonheart6?

Comment: @RiverLi See my proof for ${\dfrac {{a}^{2}}{b}}+{\dfrac {{b}^{2}}{c}}+{\dfrac {{c}^{2}}{a}}\geqslant {\dfrac {3\,{t}^{4}-4\,{t}^{3}-5\,{t}^{2}-2\,t-1}{ \left( t-1 \right) \left( 1+2\,t \right)  \left( t+1 \right) }}$ : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1101515h2258534_cylic_inequality

Comment: It is nice. $(-2X-p)r+q(p^2-2q)-p(a-b)(b-c)(-c+a)$ is nice. $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2\ge 0$ is helpful in some inequalities when using pqr method. $(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2$ is equal to the discriminant.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes. And are you are dragonheart6$?$

Comment: @tthnew A question: From $(-2X-p)r+q(p^2-2q)\ge p(a-b)(b-c)(-c+a)$, you should assume that $\mathrm{RHS}$ is non-negative before taking square on both sides?

Comment: @tthnew Do not ask it again. I will not answer Yes or No. I think that you are smart. For example, I think that some id in MSE is Hangdaj in AoPS, I will not ask him "are you Hangdaj"?

Comment: @tthnew When someone sent you private message in AoPS, "You are good at writing Maple codes.", you should know  the answer.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, Hangdaj and nangtoando is one,

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, because if $(a-b)(b-c)(a-c) <0$ then we have the result. But in my way, since $RHS \leqslant p|(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)| =p\sqrt{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2},$ I think we don't need to assuming because we are proving the stronger inequality! But $(a-b)(b-c)(a-c) \geqslant 0$ is need to find the equality cases.

Comment: @tthnew You should be careful when you take squares on both sides, that is, $A \ge B$ can not imply $A^2 \ge B^2$. Another way to write it: Let $X = a^2/b+b^2/c+c^2/a$. We have the identity $(-2X-p)r+q(p^2-2q) = p(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)$, blablabla

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, thanks.

Comment: @tthnew  By TaHongQuang at AoPS: Let $a, b, c > 0; \ a+b+c = 1; \ ab+bc+ca = \frac{1}{3+x^2}\ $ ($x\ge 0$). Then
${\frac {{a}^{3}}{b}}+{\frac {{b}^{3}}{c}}+{\frac {{c}^{3}}{a}}\ge {\frac
{{x}^{5}+{x}^{4}+2\,{x}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}+x+1}{ \left( x+1 \right)
\left( {x}^{2}+3 \right) }}$. See: Problem THQ218 in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h432676p13134045

Comment: @RiverLi See my proof for another inequality with $\sum \dfrac{a^3}{b}$: https://diendantoanhoc.net/topic/192978-ch%E1%BB%A9ng-minh-dfraca3bdfracb3cdfracc3a-geqslant-dfracq43-2qq/

Comment: @tthnew That inequality is weaker than Problem THQ218 above, right?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, I also think so. But it's nice. THQ218 can be prove by the same way.

Comment: @tthnew I noticed that for $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}$ or $\frac{a^3}{b} + \frac{b^3}{c}+ \frac{c^3}{a}$, we set $ab+bc+ca = \frac{1}{3+x^2}$, but for $\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{a}$, we set $ab+bc+ca = \frac{1-x^2}{3}$.

Comment: @RiverLi You check "the strong" of THQ263: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h432676p17575165

Comment: @tthnew THQ263 is weaker than THQ218, right?

Comment: @RiverLi I don't certain, I have not checked.

Comment: @tthnew I checked before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOS helps!

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{13a^2+4b^2+4c^2+8ab+8ac+35bc}\geq\frac{1}{4(a+b+c)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b+c}{13a^2+4b^2+4c^2+8ab+8ac+35bc}-\frac{1}{12(a+b+c)}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{8b^2+8c^2-13a^2+4ab+4ac-11bc}{13a^2+4b^2+4c^2+8ab+8ac+35bc}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(c-a)(13a-11b+16c)-(a-b)(13b-11c+16a)}{13a^2+4b^2+4c^2+8ab+8ac+35bc}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\tfrac{13b-11c+16a}{13b^2+4a^2+4c^2+8ab+8bc+35ac}-\tfrac{13a-11c+16b}{13a^2+4b^2+4c^2+8ab+8ac+35bc}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\tfrac{(a-b)^2(52a^2+95ab+52b^2-142(a+b)c+103c^2)}{(13a^2+4b^2+4c^2+8ab+8ac+35bc)(13b^2+4a^2+4c^2+8ab+8bc+35ac)}\geq0,$$ which is true by C-S and AM-GM:
$$52a^2+95ab+52b^2-142(a+b)c+103c^2=$$
$$=\frac{95}{2}(a+b)^2+\frac{9}{2}(a^2+b^2)+103c^2-142(a+b)c\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{95}{2}(a+b)^2+\frac{9}{4}(a+b)^2+103c^2-142(a+b)c=$$
$$=\frac{199}{4}(a+b)^2+103c^2-142(a+b)c\geq\left(\sqrt{199\cdot103}-142\right)(a+b)c\geq0.$$

Comment: It is a nice solution. (+1)

Comment: Thank you, dear @River Li

Comment: Wow. By hand, you get the same as my computer SOS!

Comment: What is SOS ???

Comment: @Diger It's the Sum Of Squares method. How it works you can see in my post.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg for symmetric inequality, not always $S_a,S_b,S_c \geqslant 0.$ Since $\sum G(a,b,c)(a-c)(b-c) (a-b)^2=0,$ where $G(a,b,c)$ is symmetric between $a,b.$ Sometimes it's betters to take $S_a+G(a,b,c)(a-c)(b-c),$ then choose $G(a,b,c)$ such as $S_a \geqslant 0,$ I think. But for this inequality, $S_a \geq 0$ already so we don't need it. What do you think in case $S_a<0$ or etc?

Comment: @tthnew In this case there is $a-c\geq b-c$ and if it does not work we can use $b(a-c)\geq a(b-c).$ All these for $a\geq b\geq c\geq 0$, of course.

Comment: But if the polynomials is cyclic, what you will do?

Comment: @tthnew If so, there is $uvw$ after squaring or there is the SS (SOS Schur method) and more...

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes, same way as mine. But for inequality with many equality cases, that is not easy to prove by SOS or SS, I think.

Comment: Sometimes it also works. But I agree, it's much more complicated and sometimes it's better to look for another idea.